# History of the Taxonomy of Quadrilaterals

Tags: soft-question, ho.history-overview, euclidean-geometry

> **Question:**
>
> - how did the classification of quadrilaterals come into being? Was there a single major contributor who coined terms like "rectangle", "square", "trapez/ium/oid", "kite", "deltoid", etc. or were these definitions contributed by several individuals over a longer stretch of time?
> - what was the motivation for adding quadrilaterals with specific properties to the taxonomy; is it  because the validity of certain theorems is restricted to them or is the motivation something else and what is it then?
> - why are by far fewer kinds of deltoids classified than convex quadrilaterals?

Comment: This might be more appropriate at the history of math stackexchange.

Comment: When I was in school, I recall that what the British called a "trapezium" the Americans called a "trapezoid" (and vice versa, I think).  I'm not sure if that's still the case, but at any rate, I've often wondered how the divergence in terminology came about.

Comment: @TimothyChow --- there seems to be a 1795 source for this confusion (I've added the reference to the answer), but why the US and the UK followed different path ways remains a mystery.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Q1.** If one wishes to single out one main early contributor to the systematic classification of convex quadrilaterals it would have to be the 9th century Indian mathematician [Mahavira](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mah%C4%81v%C4%ABra_(mathematician)), who divided quadrilaterals into five classes: those with unequal sides (mainly cyclic quadrilaterals, having a circumcircle), all sides equal (rhombus and square), opposite sides equal (parallelogram and rectangle), two opposite sides equal (isosceles trapezium), and three sides equal (trapezium with three equal sides). See for example [Mathematical Achievements of Pre-modern Indian Mathematicians.](https://books.google.nl/books?id=DAPLaxw-53IC&pg=PA257)

The names used by Mahavira (e.g. "*sama*" for a square and "*dvidsama*" for a rectangle) were of course not the Latin names we use today, but that seems of less significance. Some of these Latin names have a remarkably late date of first use, it seems "*rhombus*" was not used until the 16th century ([source](http://jeff560.tripod.com/r.html)).

In response to Timothy Chow's question: the two different definitions of trapezium versus trapezoid appear to originate from the 1795 [Mathematical and Philosophical Dictionary](https://books.google.nl/books?id=035RAAAAYAAJ) by Charles Hutton, in which the definitions of the two terms were reversed. The US followed that reversed definition, the UK did not ([source](http://jeff560.tripod.com/t.html)).

**Q2.** In a fun and inspiring [posting](http://mzone.mweb.co.za/residents/profmd/classify.pdf), Ben Hambrecht argues for "length-angle" duality as the key organizing principle that motivates the taxonomy.

[image]

Comment: *those with unequal sides (cyclic quadrilaterals)* Uh? Not all quadrilateral with unequal sides are cyclic.

Comment: thanks, Mahavira only considered the cyclic ones, I should specify that.

Comment: @CarloBeenakker nice and complete answer as always.